# Preservation Proof (Pierce exercise 2.2.8)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

In Benjamin C. Pierce's *Types and Programming Languages*, there's an exercise 2.2.8 that is as follows:
Suppose that $R$ is a binary relation on a set $S$, and $P$ is a predicate on $S$ that is preserved $R$. Show that $P$ is also preserved by $R^{*}$.

Is this attempt any good?:

Let $R, R^*, P$ as defined.

Suppose $(x,y)$ are in $R^*$. We want to show $P(x) = P(y)$.

If $(x,y)$ are in R, we're done since $P$ is preserved by $R$.

If $x=y$ (so that $(x,y) = (y,z)$), it follows that $P(x) = P(x) = P(y)$, as required.

Suppose that we have $(x,y)$ in $R$ and $(y,z)$ in $R$. So then $(x,z)$ will be in $R^*$ (by transitive closure). Note that since $P$ respects $R$, we have $P(x) = P(y) = P(z)$. So we have $P(x) = P(z)$ and P is also preserved by $R^*$.

Comment: Try proving it yourself.

Comment: why u gotta do me like that cuz @Berci

Comment: @clovis I think it could be said more diplomatically, but it's generally necessary that you provide your own attempt at the exercise, since Math.SE is not a homework-solution site. What have you tried? Where do you get stuck? Which of the definitions do you not understand?

Comment: @Vsotvep I tried something (added it) but I'm not sure if it's legit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be a relation on $S$ and let $P \subseteq S$ such that $P$ is *preserved* by $R$:
$$\forall x \forall y \Bigl(x \in P \wedge \langle x, y \rangle \in R \rightarrow y \in P \Bigr)$$
Let $R^*$ denote the *reflexive transitive closure* of $R$. Then $R^*$ meets the following conditions:

1. $R \subseteq R^*$ ($R^*$ *contains* $R$)
2. $\forall x \in S\colon\langle x, x \rangle \in R^*$ ($R^*$ is *reflexive*)
3. $\forall x \forall y \forall z \Bigl(\langle x, y \rangle \in R^* \wedge \langle y, z \rangle \in R^* \rightarrow \langle x, z \rangle \in R^*\Bigr)$ ($R^*$ is *transitive*)
4. $\forall T \Bigl(T \text{ fulfills conditions 1-3} \rightarrow R^* \subseteq T\Bigr)$ ($R^*$ is the *smallest* such relation)

We wish to prove that $P$ is preserved by $R^*$.

Notice that we are basically trying to prove that $x \in P \rightarrow y \in P$ holds for all $\langle x, y \rangle \in R^*$. So we are interested in proving a statement *for all* ordered pairs in $R^*$. This is reminiscent of proving "for all"-statements involving the natural numbers. In the natural number case our main tool is **induction**.

But our *inductive* definition of the reflexive transitive closure gives rise to it's very own principle of (*structural*) induction (you might want to compare this to the content of Section 3.3 in Pierce's TAPL).

To uncover this induction principle and prove our initial goal we'll first define a set of ordered pairs that satisfy our condition:
$$\mathcal{I} = \Bigl\{\langle x, y \rangle \in R^* : x \in P \rightarrow y \in P\Bigr\} $$

If we manage to prove that $\mathcal{I}$ is reflexive, transitive and contains $R$, then we could conclude that $R^* \subseteq \mathcal{I}$ (by letting $T=\mathcal{I}$ in the minimality condition of $R^*$).

- **Reflexivity** of $\mathcal{I}$: Let $x \in S$. By reflexivity of $R^*$ we have $\langle x, x \rangle \in R^*$. Combined with the tautology $x \in P \rightarrow x \in P$ we can say that $\langle x, x \rangle \in \mathcal{I}$.
- **Transitivity** of $\mathcal{I}$: Let $\langle x, y \rangle, \langle y, z \rangle \in \mathcal{I}$. Then $\langle x, y \rangle, \langle y, z \rangle \in R^*$, $x \in P \rightarrow y \in P$ and $y \in P \rightarrow z \in P$. By transitivity of $R^*$ we have $\langle x, z \rangle \in R^*$ and by [Hypothetical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism) we have $x \in P \rightarrow z \in P$. Thus $\langle x, z \rangle \in \mathcal{I}$.
- $\mathcal{I}$ **contains** $R$: Let $\langle x, y \rangle \in R$. Since $R \subseteq R^*$ we have $\langle x, y \rangle \in R^*$. Now suppose that $x \in P$. Since $\langle x, y \rangle \in R \wedge x \in P$ and $P$ is **preserved** by $R$, we have $y \in P$. Hence $x \in P \rightarrow y \in P$ and combined with $\langle x, y \rangle \in R^*$ we have $\langle x, y \rangle \in \mathcal{I}$.

Hence $R^* \subseteq \mathcal{I}$ (we can in fact say that $R^* = \mathcal{I}$ as the other inclusion $\mathcal{I} \subseteq R^*$ follows directly from the construction of $\mathcal{I}$). Equipped with this information we can conclude that $P$ is also preserved by $R^*$ almost immediately.

Let $x \in P$ and $\langle x, y \rangle \in R^*$. But then $\langle x, y \rangle \in \mathcal{I}$ because $R^* \subseteq \mathcal{I}$. In particular we then know that $x \in P \rightarrow y \in P$. One application of Modus ponens tells us that $y \in P$. Hence $x \in P \wedge \langle x, y \rangle \in R^* \rightarrow y \in P$ for all $x,y$ as required.